# How does openssh client connect to VMs using cert based keys when the server doesn't list them

Tags: ssh, certificate, rsa, openssh

How does openssh client connect to VMs using cert based keys like ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com etc when the certificate based algorithms are not enumerated in server-sig-algs. Shouldn't the authentication fail if the negotiation fails or how is OpenSSH handling this scenario?

I tried connecting to an Ubuntu VM using OpenSSH client version 8.6p1 and the server is on 8.9p1. I tried connecting using a certificate ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com xxxxxx and the connection is successful although sshd -T on the VM lists only rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com, rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com as the pubkeyacceptedalgorithms. Does OpenSSH client do any algo upgrades before negotiating with the server to achieve this? If so, how does OpenSSH negotiate with the server if the server clearly doesn't list certificate based algorithms in server-sig-algs list?